# Unable to configure DSE from Opscenter

Tags: datastax-enterprise, opscenter, datastax-startup

I am trying to configure DSE on newly configured centos 7 VM but I am getting error **Attempting to configure dse-full 5.1.0, but found a different version installed. Upgrades and downgrades aren't supported." (opscd-pool-4)** I am not able to understand why getting this error when the machine is completely new, even I haven't run any DSE command.

```
ERROR: Received error from node event-subtype="MeldError" job-id="a38724e1-2139-45f5-9266-079638c2ca2e" name="cassandra-5" ssh-management-address="192.168.159.175" node-id="dafe635a-6e98-4ae6-b0ea-6afa0da51731" event-type="error" message="Attempting to configure dse-full 5.1.0, but found a different version installed. Upgrades and downgrades aren't supported." (opscd-pool-4)
```

I am using Opscentre to configure Node.

Here you go detailed log of LCM

```
2017-11-29 05:38:37,753 [opscenterd]  INFO: configure job started for node name="cassandra-5" ssh-management-address="192.168.138.237" node-id="dafe635a-6e98-4ae6-b0ea-6afa0da51731" (async-thread-macro-32)
2017-11-29 05:38:37,776 [opscenterd]  INFO: Trying to establish ssh connection name="cassandra-5" ssh-management-address="192.168.138.237" node-id="dafe635a-6e98-4ae6-b0ea-6afa0da51731" node-name="cassandra-5" job-id="4fae4fe1-ca3c-4924-abdb-62c4cf4ad878" (async-thread-macro-32)
2017-11-29 05:38:38,515 [opscenterd]  INFO: Received milestone from node name="cassandra-5" ssh-management-address="192.168.138.237" node-id="dafe635a-6e98-4ae6-b0ea-6afa0da51731" message="Uploaded facts to OpsCenter server" job-id="4fae4fe1-ca3c-4924-abdb-62c4cf4ad878" (opscd-pool-0)
2017-11-29 05:38:40,135 [opscenterd] ERROR: Received error from node event-subtype="MeldError" job-id="4fae4fe1-ca3c-4924-abdb-62c4cf4ad878" name="cassandra-5" ssh-management-address="192.168.138.237" node-id="dafe635a-6e98-4ae6-b0ea-6afa0da51731" event-type="error" message="Attempting to configure dse-full 5.1.0, but found a different version installed. Upgrades and downgrades aren't supported." (opscd-pool-7)
2017-11-29 05:38:40,161 [opscenterd] ERROR: Configure job 4fae4fe1-ca3c-4924-abdb-62c4cf4ad878 failed! (async-thread-macro-33)
2017-11-29 05:38:41,102 [opscenterd]  INFO: configure job finished for node name="cassandra-5" ssh-management-address="192.168.138.237" node-id="dafe635a-6e98-4ae6-b0ea-6afa0da51731" (async-thread-macro-32)
```

Here you go node info:

```
[root@li1639-135 ~]# dpkg -l dse-full
    -bash: dpkg: command not found
```

**[root@li1639-135 ~]# yum info dse-full**

```
Loaded plugins: fastestmirror

base                                                     | 3.6 kB     00:00     
extras                                                   | 3.4 kB     00:00     
updates                                                  | 3.4 kB     00:00     
(1/4): base/7/x86_64/group_gz                              | 156 kB   00:00     
(2/4): extras/7/x86_64/primary_db                          | 130 kB   00:00     
(3/4): base/7/x86_64/primary_db                            | 5.7 MB   00:00     
(4/4): updates/7/x86_64/primary_db                         | 3.6 MB   00:00     
Determining fastest mirrors
 * base: mirrors.linode.com
 * extras: mirrors.linode.com
 * updates: mirrors.linode.com
Error: No matching Packages to list
```

Job ID4fae4fe1-ca3c-4924-abdb-62c4cf4ad878

```
11/29/2017, 5:38:40AM UTC ERROR - MELDERROR Attempting to configure dse-full 5.1.0, but found a different version installed. Upgrades and downgrades aren't supported.
11/29/2017, 5:38:40AM UTC SHELL-COMMAND - RESULT Finished executing command: rpm -qa | grep -E ^dse-full-[[:digit:]] | grep 5.1.0
11/29/2017, 5:38:39AM UTC SHELL-COMMAND - INVOCATION Invoked command: rpm -qa | grep -E ^dse-full-[[:digit:]] | grep 5.1.0
11/29/2017, 5:38:39AM UTC CHECK - IS-PACKAGE-INSTALLED Checking if package dse-full is installed with version 5.1.0
11/29/2017, 5:38:39AM UTC CHANGE - PACKAGE-PROXY Not using proxy
11/29/2017, 5:38:38AM UTC MILESTONE - UPLOADED-FACTS Uploaded facts to OpsCenter server
11/29/2017, 5:38:38AM UTC SHELL-COMMAND - INVOCATION Invoked command: if [ -x "$(which yum)" ] && [ -f "/etc/redhat-release" -o -f "/etc/SuSE-release" -o -f "/etc/system-release" ]; then echo -n "yum"; elif [ -x "$(which...
```

Comment: This should be fixed in OpsCenter 6.1.5. Please let me know if that works for you.

Comment: I am getting an error in 6.1.5 only.

Answer (score 1):

### Updated Answer

I was able to sync up with Ranjeet offline and found that the logs posted above were the result of configure jobs, which require that DSE is already installed. When running install jobs, things proceeded as expected.

There were also some issues with newly supported platforms and platform checks working in confusing ways, but none of that is reflected in the logs for the original post in this question.

### Original Answer

OpsCenter/LCM engineer here, I work on the provisioning features.

1. "Attempting to configure dse-full 5.1.0, but found a different version installed. Upgrades and downgrades aren't supported." The meaning of the error message seems pretty clear. You're asking OpsCenter/LCM to install/configure DSE 5.1.0. Are you positive that you don't have a different version already installed?
2. On apt-based target machines, you can check what version of DSE is install with 'dpkg -l dse-full'
3. On yum-based target machines, you can check what version of DSE is installed with 'yum info dse-full'
4. If you're really trying to install DSE 5.1.0, but a different version is already present on your nodes, you'll have to upgrade/downgrade outside OpsCenter LCM and can the resume managing configs with LCM after the desired version is installed. See http://docs.datastax.com/en/upgrade/doc/upgrade/datastax_enterprise/upgrdDSE.html
5. If you're attempting to install some other version (which matches what's already installed), then you'll have to clone your config profile and set the correct DSE version when you create the new CP. See: https://support.datastax.com/hc/en-us/articles/212267063-Lifecycle-Manager-Cloning-Configuration-Profiles
6. If you believe the error from OpsCenter/LCM is mistaken, and that you don't really have a different version of DSE installed on the target nodes, then we'll need more log snippets from LCM with the events leading up to the error, and information about how you confirmed the DSE version on all nodes.

Comment: Hey Mike if you will go through my question I clearly mentioned I did not run a single command on my new node but I am not able to understand why getting this error when the machine is completely new, even I haven't run any DSE command.

Comment: I haven't heard other reports of this behavior, but as mentioned above there are other job-events in your job-log that show how LCM determines whether DSE is installed or not, and I suggested some simplified commands to check as well. If you think LCM is misdetecting a DSE install where there is none then you need to post the relevant job-events where LCM looks for and erroneously finds DSE installed, and the results of the commands I suggested in step 2 and 3 of my response.

Comment: Due to character limitation, I have updated LCM logs and Node package info to my question only.

Comment: Hrmph. It certainly does look like the error is being issued erroneously. The updated info in your post is helpful, but omits some critical context. In the LCM UI in Jobs -> Failed Job page -> Failed node page there is a list of "job-events". In the middle of the list should be a series like "Installing DSE" "Invoked command: apt cache madison..." "Finished executing command: ...".  There's a pretty large number of these that could be relevant, the easiest way to communicate it might be to turn on debug logging and run another job, which will make the job-events show up in opscenterd.log...

Comment: But those "Finished executing command: ..." events should have stdout and stderr output for the command, and with luck one of them may show the command and results where we're incorrectly assessing that DSE is already installed. But basically we're looking for any relevant commands after the "Installing DSE" event that might let us know why LCM is confused.

Comment: There are also some "Checking if package foo is installed" events that are followed by command invocations that might be the best place to start. Sadly, we don't record results for those commands, but we do record the command that we run and you should be able to run them yourself to see what the output is.

Comment: I have re-updated my question with LCM detailed logs. Please check and let me know if you need some more information.

Comment: '11/29/2017, 5:38:40AM UTC SHELL-COMMAND - RESULT Finished executing command: rpm -qa | grep -E ^dse-full-[[:digit:]] | grep 5.1.0'

This is the the critical job-event. There's an icon to the left of this line in the UI. If you click into it it will show you the stderr and stdout for this command, or you can run it manually and see what you get. These will tell us exactly why LCM is confused.

Comment: I did not get any out after executing manually directly on node rpm -qa | grep -E ^dse-full-[[:digit:]] | grep 5.1.0  
root@li1474-22 ~]# rpm -qa | grep -E ^dse-full-[[:digit:]] | grep 5.1.0
[root@li1474-22 ~]#

Comment: Odd. No output is expected if dse-full is not installed, so I'm not sure why LCM is claiming that it is installed. I think your best best at this point is to open up the job event in the UI and paste the stdout, stderr, and exit-code so I have all the info exactly as LCM saw it.

Comment: I did not understand. Cau you explain little detail?

Comment: What I understand you need LCM Output of 11/29/2017, 5:38:40AM UTC SHELL-COMMAND - RESULT- Before {} and after {
  "stdout": "",
  "stderr": "",
  "return_code": 1
}

Comment: That output is what I was looking for, and it looks as it should. As I compare your list of job events to my own, I fail to see 3 additional job-events that I expect to see. Do you have: "Checking if any version of package dse-full is installed" then "Invoked command" followed by "SHELL-COMMAND - RESULT"? Note that these events are checking for "any version" of dse vs the events you posted looking specifically for 5.1.0. Again, the interesting bit will be the stdout, stderr, and return_code of the command-result event.

Comment: Hey Mike, the logs that I have shared is all that I see. There's no other job events. Please let me know if you need anything more from me.

Comment: I'm stumped. I don't think there's anything more that I can do to help you via stackoverflow. If you have DataStax support, open a support ticket and request to have your support ticket escalated to me. If you're in the startup program, reach out to your contact in the program, mention me by name, and tell them that even though you don't have support the LCM engineering team wants to work with you to resolve a difficult to reproduce problem that might affect all customers. Perhaps via screenshare we can get further.